# Find location of highest point density in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, density

How do I find the location of highest density of points in QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Heatmap](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/interpolation.html#qgisheatmapkerneldensityestimation). Set a search radius, output raster size and `kernel_shape=Uniform` (Advanced options)
2. [Raster pixels to points](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgispixelstopoints) to create a point in each raster cell center with the column `VALUE` storing the cell value.
3. Extract or Select by expression: `"VALUE"=maximum( expression:="VALUE")`to find the point(s) with the highest point count.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to restrict the search region?

Comment: You can for example either [clip](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#gdalcliprasterbymasklayer) the raster or [clip](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgisclip) the point layer before the selection/extraction